# What is the correct wget command syntax for HTTPS with username and password?

Tags: wget

I would like to download a file remotely with this URL using wget:

```
https://test.mydomain.com/files/myfile.zip
```

The site test.mydomain.com requires a login. I would like to download that file in my another server using this command but it does not work (does not completely download the file):

```
wget --user=myusername --password=mypassword https://test.mydomain.com/files/myfile.zip
```

If my username is myusername and password is mypassword what would be the correct wget syntax?

The following are the return messages after I type the above command:

```
Resolving test.mydomain.com (test.mydomain.com)... 123.456.789
Connecting to test.mydomain.com (test.mydomain.com)|123.456.789|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://test.mydomain.com/login/unauthorized [following]
--2013-01-30 02:01:32--  https://test.mydomain.com/login/unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to test.mydomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://test.mydomain.com/login [following]
--2013-01-30 02:01:32--  https://test.mydomain.com/login
Reusing existing connection to test.mydomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `myfile.zip'
```

Am I missing something? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: checkthis out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication

Comment: Just did a quick Google search and found [this link.](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html) It seems you need to add the parameter `--secure-protocol=protocol`, with protocol being  ‘auto’, ‘SSLv2’, ‘SSLv3’, or ‘TLSv1’.

Comment: It doesn't completely download the file. So it has downloaded part of the file?

Comment: I see the file created on my server but it is not the correct file size. Sort of the wget command only created the file but does not download the contents.

Comment: Take a try on this addon, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/, it will help you get the correct wget command.

Comment: Actually cliget is HIGHLY recommended if the answer below does not work. I suggest everyone having an issue with wget should try it.

Comment: @thomasbabuj Page removed.

Comment: @Rodrigo It's still on the Wayback Machine - try https://web.archive.org/web/20170818004821/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication

Answer (score 105, accepted):

By specifying the option --user and --ask-password wget will ask for the credentials. Below is an example. Change the username and download link to your needs.

```
wget --user=username --ask-password https://xyz.com/changelog-6.40.txt
```

Comment: +1 for using `--ask-password` instead of providing it in plaintext to be seen in the shell history.

Comment: if you use wget in a script --ask-password is useless

Comment: Thank's

And how do I securely store the password on linux, and does this wget authenticate automatically, without having to enter username and password?

Answer (score 27):

I have found that  wget does not properly authenticate with some servers, perhaps because it is only HTTP 1.0 compliant. In such cases, curl (which is HTTP 1.1 compliant) usually does the trick:

`curl -o <filename-to-save-as> -u <username>:<password> <url>`

Comment: wget supports HTTP 1.1 [since 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Notable_releases)

Comment: Thanks. No idea what's going on but wget just won't send the headers for me. curl works fine.

Comment: @DavidSiegal how to use curl for downloading files from `google drive`. I used the code `curl -u email@gmail.com:pass https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive/3521.jpg > 3521.jpg` it download me a file, but it cannot be open?

Comment: It be would recommended to specify just the username in command, let it ask the password and then enter it. Just to prevent password being seen in commands history.

Comment: @berbt Your wikipedia link about wget supporting HTTP 1.1 get its source from a terse revision comment ["Mention support for HTTP/1.1"](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/revision/2336). It's not clear whether that means full or only partial support. The official [Wget FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html#Does_Wget_understand_HTTP.2F1.1.3F) says the latter.

Answer (score 13):

It's not that your file is partially downloaded. It fails authentication and hence downloads e.g "index.html" but it names it myfile.zip (since this is what you want to download).

I followed the link suggested by @thomasbabuj and figured it out eventually.

You should try adding `--auth-no-challenge` and as @thomasbabuj suggested replace your password entry

I.e

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --user=myusername --ask-password https://test.mydomain.com/files/myfile.zip
```

Comment: `man wget` on `--auth-no-challenge`: "Use of this option is not recommended, and is intended only to support some few obscure servers, which never send HTTP authentication challenges, but accept unsolicited auth info, say, in addition to form-based authentication."

Comment: Yeah, good input. I'm using curl whenever possible, but if wget is a must, the `--auth-no-challenge` is a must in certain automised environments. I don't agree with "obscure server" notation.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the same address with HTTP instead of HTTPS. Be aware that this does use HTTP instead of HTTPS and only some sites might support this method.

Example address: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso

`wget http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso`

*notice the `http://` instead of `https://`.

This is probably not recommended though :)

If you can, try use curl.

---

EDIT:

FYI an example with username (and prompt for password) would be:

`curl --user $USERNAME -O http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso`

Where `-O` is

```
 -O, --remote-name
              Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off.)
```