# Automate Logging into a HTTPS page and downloading a file c#

Tags: c#, authentication, https, webclient, webrequest

I've attempted a dozen or so different code examples found on SO from other questions as well as trying myself with WebClient and WebRequests but I keep getting the same response. There are no errors. The connection happens but the response I get is the source for the login page and no cookie returned.

The site is: https://www.mft3.firstdataclients.com/cgi-bin/messageway/mwi.cgi

I've done the view source and modified all the variations I've used to post "user" and "password" in the post but still no cookie and the response is simply html source for that same page.

I'm obviously doing something wrong as others have said the examples I've tried works for them...

Some examples of what I've tried:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.BaseAddress = URL;
var data = new NameValueCollection();
data.Add("user", userName);
data.Add("password", passWord);
var resp = client.UploadValues(URL, data);
using (var stream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(resp)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(stream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

[C# https login and download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841344/c-sharp-https-login-and-download-file)

[HttpClient and forms authentication in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640116/httpclient-and-forms-authentication-in-c-sharp)

Don't want to dump all of them here but I've done my research first. They all return the same frustrating login page source.

http://screencast.com/t/Eow7FVHW

Thoughts, suggestions, rude remarks? I've got a day and a half to make this work before I end up having to pass it off to someone else. It seems like it should be much simpler than that...

EDIT: Occasionally I get empty cookies back. I can't tell if this is progress in the right direction or not...

http://screencast.com/t/SxWYDP7Kba2a

EDIT2: Fiddler reveals all! I was missing a post param to indicate I wanted to log in.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.BaseAddress = URL;
var data = new NameValueCollection();
data.Add("user", userName);
data.Add("password", passWord);
data.Add("request", "Logon");
var temp = "";
var resp = client.UploadValues(URL, data);
using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(resp)))
{
      temp += reader.ReadToEnd();
      Console.WriteLine(temp);
}
```

Comment: I've never done this before but I feel like it can be easily accomplished with wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595554/what-is-the-correct-wget-command-syntax-for-https-with-username-and-password

Comment: If you are running this on windows, you would have to install wget for windows http://superuser.com/a/25540/340004